# Format cells in excel for decimal places using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

How can I format Cell (D:) 2 decimals places Cell (E:) 1 decimal place and Cell (H:)3 decimals places in excel using a macro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the numberformat property of a range will format it to any custom format

```
  sheets("sheet1").range("D:D").numberformat = "0.00"
  sheets("sheet1").range("E:E").numberformat = "0.0"
  sheets("sheet1").range("H:H").numberformat = "0.000"
```

for numbers with a comma or currency displayed this would work:

```
   sheets("sheet1").range("D:D").numberformat = "&#,##0"
```

Comment: Is this another question ("like this?"), or an answer? Please rephrase it to include an explanation and remove the question. :-)