# Unable to convert general to decimal in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code and i am trying to convert a range to decimal.

```
Range("V2:V1000").Columns.Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
 (column by column)

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(XlsFile)
Range("P2", Range("AB1000").End(xlUp)).NumberFormat = "#.00"

(range of columns)
```

none worked. It doesnt throw any error, but the numbers are still without decimals. Any help please.

Update:

[[image: Example]

Comment: you make a comment about column by column, but V2:V1000 is only 1 column.  are you number only in column V or are they in other columns as well?  if so those columns would be unaffected. in your second case, if AB1:AB1000 is empty then your selected range is really P1:AB2.  Without known your data this may be ok.

Comment: I actually meant column "S". I'm not sure what is wrong with S

Comment: take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962656/format-cells-in-excel-for-decimal-places-using-a-macro) see if it helps any.  Seems there they defined what worksheet they were doing the number formatting on.

Comment: ok when trying to debug this I had multiple workbooks open.  make sure you are defining which worksheet you were working with, and I would go as far as which work book too.  Second make sure the number you are dealing with actually have more or less than 2 decimals or you wont notice the difference.

Comment: tried that . didnt work. oh my god. this is killing me. I wrote an entire macro, but cant convert to decimal. ?? Any other ways to convert an entire range or a column to decimal

Answer (score 0):

Using the following worked for me:

```
Range("V2:V1000").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

If it doesn't work for you, please post a screenshot of your sheet, maybe you have some screwy circumstances affecting your cells?